# What do I have to do to convert a DIB to a BMP?

Tags: windows, image

What do I have to do to convert a DIB to a BMP?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the Bitmap Header Types is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183386%28VS.85%29.aspx.

In code, the difference between a bmp file and a dib memory representation is the presence of the BITMAPFILEHEADER structure at the beginning (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx). So the literal answer for converting bmp to dib is to skip the BITMAPFILEHEADER and begin with the memory address of the DIB header (immediately following the bitmap file header), which is always 14 bytes past the beginning of the bmp memory address.

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER *bmp = ...;
char * bmpBytes = reinterpret_cast<char *>(bmp);
void * myDib = (void *)bmpBytes + BMP_HEADER_LENGTH; /* (14 bytes) */
/* cast and do something with myDib */
...
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Check the API GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib

Example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/DIBtoBitmap.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Imagemagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/formats.html) convert function will do this (and many other conversions) for you on the command line. Free, open source, available on all major platforms. This is a great piece of software that should be in anyone's toolbox.

Comment: Where Exactly is the DOS command utility software. Can't seem to find it, only the complete source code.

Comment: windows 32 binaries are at the bottom of this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php